# Release disk space used by cgi.FieldStorage temp files

Tags: linux, pyramid, wsgi

I am writing a pyramid application that accepts many large file uploads (as a `POST`). Similar to [How can I serve temporary files from Python Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949077/how-can-i-serve-temporary-files-from-python-pyramid), I'm having a problem where the the temp files created by cgi.FieldStorage are orphaned, consuming GB's of disk space. `lsof` indicates that my wsgi process has deleted files from `/tmp` but the files haven't been closed. Restarting the application clears the orphans.

How can I cause these files to be closed so that the disk space is returned to the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem I encountered was unrelated to cgi.FieldStorage, pyramid actually uses [WebOb](http://webob.org/) for serializing data.

The cause of the high disk space usage was `pyramid_debugtoolbar`. The debugger states in it's documentation that it maintains the data from the previous 100 requests, which took up a great amount of memory and disk space in my case. Removing the include for the debugger from `__init__.py` and restarting the server resolved the problem.